# How do I check for the existence of a bundle in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

My application is made up with eight bundles, within my main layout I would like to check if a certain bundle exists so I can include a sub template, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @DonCallisto, I decided to make a twig function to use in my templates, the following is my twig extension.

```
<?php

namespace MG\AdminBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
class Bundles extends \Twig_Extension {
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
                'bundleExists', 
                array($this, 'bundleExists')
            ),
        );
    }


    public function bundleExists($bundle){
        return array_key_exists(
            $bundle, 
            $this->container->getParameter('kernel.bundles')
        );
    }
    public function getName() {
        return 'mg_admin_bundles';
    }
}
```

I then registered it in my services.yml

```
services:                
    mg_admin.bundles.extension:
        class: MG\AdminBundle\Twig\Bundles
        arguments: [@service_container]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now in my twig templates I can check for registered bundles like this:

```
{% if bundleExists('MGEmailBundle') %}
    {% include 'MGEmailBundle:SideBar:sidebar.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, great idea. I had it in mind but I was "running off" the keybord so I dind't wrote a "more complex" answer. This is the right way. +1 :)

Comment: you dont have to inject the whole container, just inject parameter `%kernel.bundles%`

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');
```

will return all registered bundles (class names). You could pass that list - or parse it direclty - into a controller and pass it to your twig view

Then you should easily reach your target

Answer (score -1):

If the bundle you want to check is a specific bundle, and you know the main class name, the easiest way may be:

```
if (class_exists('Acme\CommentBundle\AcmeCommentBundle'))
{
    // Bundle exists and is loaded by AppKernel...
}
```